# Running the Sort example on Hadoop (single-node cluster)

Tags: sorting, ubuntu, hadoop, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed `Hadoop single-node cluster` 0.20.2 on `Ubuntu` 10.04 and run an example using the material of the tutorial I found on this site:

http://www.dscripts.net/wiki/setup-hadoop-ubuntu-single-node

Now I am trying to run the `Sort example` on Hadoop. It needs Sequential files as input. Could anyone please `help` me `running the Sort example`? (or giving me some more info on how to generate the Sequential files as input).

Thank you in advance.. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

[Running Sort Benchmark](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Sort)

To use the sort example as a benchmark, generate 10GB/node of random data using RandomWriter. Then sort the data using the sort example. This provides a sort benchmark that scales depending on the size of the cluster. By default, the sort example uses 1.0 * capacity for the number of reduces and depending on your cluster you may see better results at 1.75 * capacity.

The commands are:

```
$> bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar randomwriter /path/randFiles
$> bin/hadoop jar hadoop-*-examples.jar sort /path/randFiles /path/resultFile
```

The first command will generate the unsorted data in the rand directory. The second command will read that data, sort it, and write into the rand-sort directory.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [RandomWriter](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.20/src/examples/org/apache/hadoop/examples/RandomWriter.java) example.  It is a job that outputs a sequence file using random data.  The key is the `job.setOutputFormat(SequenceFileOutputFormat.class)` line that specifies the output format.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try this and let you know ;)